# How to read an option from XML in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parsing, openxml

I have the next `XML` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DynamicEntity Name="ProductsMilk">
  <Field Name="Name" Type="nvarchar(256)" AllowNulls="false" />
  <Field Name="Description" Type="ntext" AllowNulls="false" />
  <Field Name="Price" Type="float" AllowNulls="false" />
</DynamicEntity>
```

I need to read some value from any option of `XML-node`, for e.g. I need to read the value of **Type** option from **Field** node using `T-SQL`.

How can I do this using internal **OpenXML** provider in `MSSQL`?

Comment: Any specific reason why you need to do this using `OpenXML`?

Comment: @ughai Why not to use the ready provider, which is already existed in MSSQL and which provides great possibilities? I know, that there are some methods from the XML type like `nodes()` which Giorgi Nakeuri has provided in answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will extract all the data from your XML:

```
DECLARE @doc VARCHAR(1000) = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <DynamicEntity Name="ProductsMilk">
      <Field Name="Name" Type="nvarchar(256)" AllowNulls="false" />
      <Field Name="Description" Type="ntext" AllowNulls="false" />
      <Field Name="Price" Type="float" AllowNulls="false" />
    </DynamicEntity>';

DECLARE @iDoc INT;

EXECUTE sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc;

SELECT  *
FROM    OPENXML(@iDoc, 'DynamicEntity/Field')
        WITH 
        (   DynamicEntityName  VARCHAR(100) '../@Name', 
            FieldName VARCHAR(100) '@Name', 
            [Type] VARCHAR(100) '@Type', 
            AllowNulls VARCHAR(100) '@AllowNulls'
        );
```

Basically, you just need to specify a column mapping for your xml attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
DECLARE @x XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DynamicEntity Name="ProductsMilk">
  <Field Name="Name" Type="nvarchar(256)" AllowNulls="false" />
  <Field Name="Description" Type="ntext" AllowNulls="false" />
  <Field Name="Price" Type="float" AllowNulls="false" />
</DynamicEntity>'


SELECT t.c.value(N'../@Name', N'nvarchar(100)'),
       t.c.value(N'@Name', N'nvarchar(100)'),
       t.c.value(N'@Type', N'nvarchar(100)'),
       t.c.value(N'@AllowNulls', N'nvarchar(100)')
FROM @x.nodes(N'/DynamicEntity/Field') t(c)
```